# Does log4net provides Max Rate feature i.e. maximum speed allowed to write logs to the file?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, security, log4net

I am interested to limit log lines per second. All I need is to limit log lines per second, because Logging subsystems are often slow compared to subsystems that might generate loggable events. Without some sort of protection, an attacker may be able to overwhelm an audit server, or keep a device so busy sending repetitive audit messages that core functions stop working.

Comment: What would you like to do with logs that exceeded your MaxRate value? You received 100 entries in 1 second, but you are allowing only 10.

Comment: I just want to limit logs lines per second to protect my application of being crashed.If logs exceed our max rate I want to drop that logs simple.Is there any way using log4net do let me know.Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing out of the box in log4net to do that. Your best option is to implement your own ForwardingAppender inhering from existing one: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/ForwardingAppender.cs After that you can specify your own different thresholds and filters.

Comment: Alright..Thank you!

Comment: @Peska Tell me one thing more. currently I am using RollingFileAppender in our application. Do I need a separate class or separate XML tag to implement ForwardingAppender in config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in comments, you can write your own ForwardingAppender. Here is an example in Console Application:

Program.cs

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Repository;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace MaxRateExample
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ILoggerRepository logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"item-{i}");
                log.Info($"item-{i}");

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MaxRateForwardingAppender.cs

```
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MaxRateExample
{
    public class MaxRateForwardingAppender : ForwardingAppender
    {
        // Maximum 10 events per second. You can move this to config file.
        private const int MaxRateSeconds = 1;
        private const int MaxRateEvents = 10;

        private List<DateTime> Dates { get; }

        public MaxRateForwardingAppender()
        {
            Dates = new List<DateTime>();
        }

        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (LogEvent())
                base.Append(loggingEvent);
        }

        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents)
        {
            if (LogEvent())
                base.Append(loggingEvents);
        }

        private bool LogEvent()
        {
            Dates.RemoveAll(x => (DateTime.Now - x).Seconds > MaxRateSeconds);

            if (Dates.Count <= MaxRateEvents)
            {
                Dates.Add(DateTime.Now);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

log4net.config

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Logs\MyLog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="MaxRateForwardingAppender" type="MaxRateExample.MaxRateForwardingAppender, MaxRateExample">
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="MaxRateForwardingAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Sample output from log file:

```
2020-01-09 15:50:05,396 INFO  item-0
2020-01-09 15:50:05,419 INFO  item-1
2020-01-09 15:50:05,430 INFO  item-2
2020-01-09 15:50:05,441 INFO  item-3
2020-01-09 15:50:05,452 INFO  item-4
2020-01-09 15:50:05,463 INFO  item-5
2020-01-09 15:50:05,474 INFO  item-6
2020-01-09 15:50:05,485 INFO  item-7
2020-01-09 15:50:05,496 INFO  item-8
2020-01-09 15:50:05,507 INFO  item-9
2020-01-09 15:50:05,518 INFO  item-10
2020-01-09 15:50:07,403 INFO  item-183
2020-01-09 15:50:07,425 INFO  item-185
2020-01-09 15:50:07,436 INFO  item-186
2020-01-09 15:50:07,447 INFO  item-187
2020-01-09 15:50:07,458 INFO  item-188
2020-01-09 15:50:07,469 INFO  item-189
2020-01-09 15:50:07,480 INFO  item-190
2020-01-09 15:50:07,491 INFO  item-191
2020-01-09 15:50:07,502 INFO  item-192
2020-01-09 15:50:07,513 INFO  item-193
2020-01-09 15:50:07,538 INFO  item-194
2020-01-09 15:50:09,406 INFO  item-366
2020-01-09 15:50:09,427 INFO  item-368
2020-01-09 15:50:09,438 INFO  item-369
2020-01-09 15:50:09,449 INFO  item-370
2020-01-09 15:50:09,460 INFO  item-371
2020-01-09 15:50:09,472 INFO  item-372
```